# ImproperlyConfigured error in creating new Django app

Tags: django

I'm getting this exact error while creating a new app(emulatorsMgmt):

*The included urlconf '<module 'apps.emulatorsMgmt' from './apps/emulatorsMgmt/**init**.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.*

Here are the related files:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.emulatorsMgmt.as_view(),name='emulatorsMgmt'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

# Create your views here.
class emulatorsMgmt(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'hello.html')
```

The hello.html is present in the templates/emulatorsMgmt folder. Also I have made the following addition in the urls.py of the central project:

```
url(r'^emulatorsMgmt/', include('apps.emulatorsMgmt'))
```

I have also added the app in my dirs of setting.py.
I wonder where I am going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `url(r'^emulatorsMgmt/', include('apps.emulatorsMgmt'))` This should be `url(r'^emulatorsMgmt/', include('apps.emulatorsMgmt.urls'))` , right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrectly included the app urls in your root urlconf. I think it should be:

```
url(r'^emulatorsMgmt/', include('apps.emulatorsMgmt.urls'))
```

Comment: *bangs head against the wall emoji*
Thanks for your help!